# Small-caps headers with no standard uppercase letters (fancyhdr)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, small-caps

Using fancyhdr to format my headers, I want them to display the current chapter name in small caps. So with no surprise I’ve ended up doing something like this:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % Clears the standard fancy style header
\fancyhead[CO]{\textsc{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}} % Displays current chapter name in small-caps on odd-numbered pages
```

Which of course works quite well, but the point is that I want no standard uppercase *at all* in the headers: in other words, I want a chapter called “The Chapter ABC” to be treated as “the chapter abc” during the small-caps-isation process. Is there any way to achieve this? I tried different solutions with things such as `\MakeLowercase` or `\MakeTextLowercase`, but they all appear ineffective within `\fancyhead{}`.

I’m obviously looking for a solution easier and more “automatic” than the one consisting in manually renaming the header with `\fancyhead{}` after each `\chapter{}`, which is the one I’m currently using...

Thanks a lot to everyone willing to help me!

Comment: Can you add some details about the document  class you're using?

Comment: what you are asking for is a contradiction.  "small caps" *by definition* have the shape of uppercase letters.  what you really want (as indicated by your example) is *all lowercase*.  if you would extend your code to be a full compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, i'm sure someone here can provide a suitable answer.  in the meantime, get rid of the `\textsc`; it is only doing something that you don't want.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I suspect what OP means is to force the *original* case to lowercase before rendering as SC. Something like `memoir`s `\chapterstyle{bringhurst}`

Comment: @Brent.Longborough -- yes, it's pretty obvious that is what the op means.  what's really the point here is understanding of the vocabulary, which is faulty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine `\chaptermark` to avoid `\MakeUppercase`; I also instruct to use `\footnotesize` for the number, or it would appear too big.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % Clears the standard fancy style
\fancyhead[CO]{\scshape\MakeLowercase{\leftmark}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{%
    \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
      \@chapapp\ {\footnotesize\thechapter}. \ %
    \fi
  #1%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{This title has Upper Case Letters}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Update `\chaptermark`; here's the default definition (from [`report.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co), but it would be similar in [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co)):

```
\def\chaptermark#1{%
  \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
    \fi
    #1}}{}}%
```

We update it to use `\scshape` and `\MakeLowercase` directly:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\scshape\MakeLowercase{%
  \ifnum\c@secnumdepth > \m@ne \@chapapp\ \thechapter.\ \fi #1}}{}}
```

Here is a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % Clears the standard fancy style header
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[CO]{\leftmark} % Displays current chapter name in small-caps on odd-numbered pages
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\scshape\MakeLowercase{%
  \ifnum\c@secnumdepth > \m@ne \@chapapp\ \protect\resizebox{!}{1.15ex}{\thechapter}.\ \fi #1}}{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{16}% Just for this example
\chapter{A Chapter}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```